# cx_freeze embedding my shared object library into the binary executable?

Tags: python, shared-libraries, cx-freeze

I'm able to use cx_freeze to package my python tool, but the library I need can't be loaded. For some reason the outputted executable/binary name keeps getting included in the path.

I get the following error:

OSError: /home/derekx/sbu/build/exe.linux-x86_64-2.7/secure_boot_utility/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: Not a directory

The library gets packaged to /home/derekx/sbu/build/exe.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0

The created binary "secure_boot_utility" is also in the build/exe.linux86_64-2.7 dir.

My input script and setup.py are in /home/derekx/sbu.

I used "python setup.py build" to package the tool/dependencies..

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried a combination of the options but still get the same error.

My setup.py is:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

sys.path.append('sbu_scripts/')
sys.path.append('lib/')

binincludes = ['libcrypto.so.1.0.0']
binpaths = ['/home/derekx/sbu/lib']
includefiles = [('lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0','lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0'),]

exe = Executable(
    script="secure_boot_utility.py",
    )

setup(
    name = "SecureBoot",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Test Secure Boot",
    options = {"build_exe": {'copy_dependent_files':True, 'create_shared_zip':True, 'bin_includes':binincludes, 'bin_path_includes':binpaths, 'include_files':includefiles}},
    executables = [exe]
    )
```

Comment: I haven't seen that before. Can you try copying the library into the same folder as the executable, rather than into the `lib/` subfolder?

Comment: Yep.  The option 'copy_dependent_files':True appears to copy a couple of the libraries I need (libcrypto included) at the same level where the executable is created.  If I set include_files to copy one level up as well, I still get the same issue when I run the executable.  Thanks

Comment: If I add zip_include to have the library added to the zip file as lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0, I still get the same error :(

Comment: Compiled libraries don't work inside zip files, they have to be real files. Can you show the directory layout with libcrypto in the same directory as the executable? And how does your code load libcrypto?

Comment: Before using cx_freeze/setup.py:

Comment: Before using cx_freeze/setup.py directory layout at script/executable level:
secure_boot_utility.py
lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
helper_scripts/global_defs.py
helper_scripts/utilities.py

after running cx_freeze/setup.py:
secure_boot_utility (executable)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0
lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0

it appears that cx_freeze also copies the libcrypto to the same level as the executable (copy_dependent_files option default appears to be true).  I can manually copy lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with the include_files option.

Comment: Sorry... still getting used to posting/adding comments.

I'm loading the library with cdll.LoadLibrary (from ctypes):
LibHandle = cdll.LoadLibrary('lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why the top level directory (getcwd) is the executable name.

Anyway I was able to add something in my code with os.path.exists and readjust the value sent to LoadLibrary.

Thanks, Thomas, for taking the time to respond.

This is originally someone else's tool that I had to support.
What was happening was sys.path[0] was being used to get the current working directory to construct the full path to the libraries being loaded.
I'm not sure why the executable that was created with cx_freeze always embedded the executable name in the the current working directory.

How I fixed it, was checked if the full path of the library that gets constructed existed with os.path.exists:

```
if os.path.exists(path_to_lib) is False:
    path_to_lib = LibName

return path_to_lib
```

This way if the full path exists, it works and if it does not just use the LibName which should pick it up from the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment setting.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, it's good practice to show the solution you worked out for later readers. There are few things as frustrating as finding that someone already solved a problem your having, and didn't say how.

Comment: Added what I did.  Thanks again

Comment: By the way, the reason the executable is on sys.path is that, with some option, the executable can have a zip file appended to it containing pure-python modules.

Comment: I tried to setting append_script_to_exe and include_in_shared_zip to False neither seemed to help.  Is it another option that you are referring to?  thanks

Comment: It wouldn't have helped with your problem, but it explains why the executable name was in `sys.path`.